# Crash on importing counter?

Tags: python

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import groupby
l = [1,2,7,7,8,9,9]
freqs = groupby(Counter(l).most_common(), lambda x:x[1])
print [val for val,count in freqs.next()[1]]
```

This is the code im using to find multiple modes but i keep on getting the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\Documents\summative.py", line 30, in -toplevel-
    from collections import Counter
ImportError: cannot import name Counter
```

is there way to fix this?

Comment: [Counter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html) is only available for Python 2.7+.

Comment: Can you import ´collections´? What is the return value of ´dir(collections)´, when you have imported it? Can you import other modules shipped with Python? Which Python version are you using, and did you do anything out of the ordinary, when installing it?

Comment: Try `import sys`, then `print sys.version` to see what you have.

Answer (score 1):

`Counter` wasn't added to the Python`collections`module until version 2.7. There's an ActiveState Cookbook [recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576611-counter-class/) by Raymond Hettinger for one that will work in 2.5 or later.